# Field Level Encryption with Spring Data JPA and JPA EntityListener

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt a handful of fields on domain entities before insert/update and decrypt them upon select to display in the UI.

I'm using Spring Data JPA repositories with Hibernate and an EntityListener which decrypts during @PostLoad lifecycle event and encrypts during @PrePersist and @PreUpdate.  The problem I have is that once the record is loaded from the DB into the PersistenceContext, the listener decrypts the data which makes the EntityManager think the entity has been altered which in turn triggers an Update and hence @PreUpdate encryption again. Any advice on how to handle this?

- Spring 4.0.4.RELEASE
- Spring Data JPA 1.5.2.RELEASE
- Hibernate 4.2.14.Final

Is there an easy way to return detached entities from the JPA Repository?

**Entity Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cases")
@EntityListeners(EncryptionListener.class)
public class MyCase implements Serializable, EncryptionEntity {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyCase.class);

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String caseNumber;
private byte[] secretProperty;
private byte[] iv;

@Id
@Column(name="case_number")
public String getCaseNumber() {
    return caseNumber;
}
public void setCaseNumber(String caseNumber) {
    this.caseNumber = caseNumber;
}

@Column(name="secret_property")
public byte[] getSecretProperty() {
    return secretProperty;
}
public void setSecretProperty(byte[] secretProperty) {
    this.secretProperty = secretProperty;
}

@Column
public byte[] getIv() {
    return iv;
}
public void setIv(byte[] iv) {
    this.iv = iv;
}

@Override
@Transient
public byte[] getInitializationVector() {
    return this.iv;
}

@Override
public void setInitializationVector(byte[] iv) {
    this.setIv(iv);
}

}
```

**EncryptionEntity Interface**

```
public interface EncryptionEntity {

    public byte[] getInitializationVector();
    public void setInitializationVector(byte[] iv);
}
```

**Spring Data JPA Repository**

```
public interface MyCaseRepository extends JpaRepository<MyCase, String> {

}
```

**MyCaseService Interface**

```
public interface MyCaseService {

    public MyCase findOne(String caseNumber);

    public MyCase save(MyCase case);

}
```

**MyCaseService Implementation**

```
public class MyCaseServiceImpl implements MyCaseService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyCaseServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private MyCaseRepository repos;


    @Override
    public MyCase findOne(String caseNumber) {
        return repos.findOne(caseNumber);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public MyCase save(MyCase case) {

        return repos.save(case);
    }

}
```

**Encryption JPA Listener Class**

```
@Component
public class EncryptionListener {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EncryptionListener.class);

    private static EncryptionUtils encryptionUtils;
    private static SecureRandom secureRandom;

    private static Map<Class<? extends EncryptionEntity>, 
        List<EncryptionEntityProperty>> propertiesToEncrypt;

    @Autowired
    public void setCrypto(EncryptionUtils encryptionUtils){
        EncryptionListener.encryptionUtils = encryptionUtils;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setSecureRandom(SecureRandom secureRandom){
        EncryptionListener.secureRandom = secureRandom;
    }

    public EncryptionListener(){

        if (propertiesToEncrypt == null){

            propertiesToEncrypt = new HashMap<Class<? extends EncryptionEntity>, List<EncryptionEntityProperty>>();

            //MY CASE
            List<EncryptionEntityProperty> propertyList = new ArrayList<EncryptionEntityProperty>();
            propertyList.add(new EncryptionEntityProperty(MyCase.class, "secretProperty", byte[].class));
            propertiesToEncrypt.put(MyCase.class, propertyList);

        }

    }

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersistEncryption(EncryptionEntity entity){
        logger.debug("PRE-PERSIST");
        encryptFields(entity);
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdateEncryption(EncryptionEntity entity){
        logger.debug("PRE-UPDATE");
        encryptFields(entity); 
    }

    public void encryptFields(EncryptionEntity entity){
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
        encryptionUtils.setIv(iv);
        entity.setInitializationVector(iv);

        logger.debug("Encrypting " + entity);

        Class<? extends EncryptionEntity> entityClass = entity.getClass();

        List<EncryptionEntityProperty> properties = propertiesToEncrypt.get(entityClass);

        for (EncryptionEntityProperty property : properties){

            logger.debug("Encrypting '{}' field of {}", property.getName(), entityClass.getSimpleName());
            if (property.isEncryptedWithIv() == false){
                logger.debug("Encrypting '{}' without IV.", property.getName());
            }

            try {
                byte[] bytesToEncrypt = (byte[]) property.getGetter().invoke(entity, (Object[]) null);

                if (bytesToEncrypt == null || bytesToEncrypt.length == 0){
                    continue;
                }

                byte[] encrypted = encryptionUtils.encrypt(bytesToEncrypt, property.isEncryptedWithIv());

                property.getSetter().invoke(entity, new Object[]{encrypted});


            } catch (Exception e){
                logger.error("Error while encrypting '{}' property of {}: " + e.getMessage(), property.getName(), entityClass.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    @PostLoad
    public void decryptFields(EncryptionEntity entity){

        logger.debug("POST-LOAD");

        logger.debug("Decrypting " + entity);

        Class<? extends EncryptionEntity> entityClass = entity.getClass();
        byte[] iv = entity.getInitializationVector();

        List<EncryptionEntityProperty> properties = propertiesToEncrypt.get(entityClass);

        for (EncryptionEntityProperty property : properties){

            try {
                byte[] value = (byte[]) property.getGetter().invoke(entity, (Object[]) null);

                if (value == null || value.length == 0){
                    logger.debug("Ignoring blank field {} of {}", property.getName(), entityClass.getSimpleName());
                    continue;
                } 

                logger.debug("Decrypting '{}' field of {}", property.getName(), entityClass.getSimpleName());
                if (property.isEncryptedWithIv() == false){
                    logger.debug("Decrypting '{}' without IV.", property.getName());
                }

                byte[] decrypted = encryptionUtils.decrypt(value, iv, property.isEncryptedWithIv());

                property.getSetter().invoke(entity, new Object[]{decrypted});

            } catch (Exception e){
                logger.error("Error while decrypting '{}' property of {}", property.getName(), entityClass.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Is `@PostLoad` invoked while calling `findOne(String caseNumber)` method ?

Comment: @wypieprz, yes, the **@PostLoad** method is triggered by the findOne method. And the **@PostUpdate** is immediately triggered after the secretProperty is decrypted.

Comment: How about executing `MyCaseServiceImpl.findOne` method outside of the persistence-context? The entities should be returned then as detached ones.

Comment: Spring creates a proxy of the MyCaseRepository that uses the EntityManager.  Not sure how to avoid the persistence context.  Perhaps if I did not annotate the findOne method with `@Transactional`? I've moved on to a different approach using my EncryptionListener as an injected component to encrypt/decrypt.  But it is certainly not as elegant as the transparent encryption/decryption I was hoping for.

Comment: I guess `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` will force detachment.

Comment: I tested that out and it works. I hesitate to configure all my find methods that way however. I suppose I could create a findOneDetached method and annotate it as `Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED` to maintain the Transactional/Non-Transactional option.  Thanks for all your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question asked is pretty old. but i was facing the same issue and to overcome, you can use PreLoadEventListener. In your `decryptFields` instead of using `@PostLoad` use `@PreLoad`